# Kill the Airflow task running on a remote location through Airflow UI

Tags: python, hadoop, airflow

The Airflow installation is on an EC2 and it is triggering scripts on the EMR.
If I use the "Clear" option from the UI, the UI shows the task with a shutdown status but I can still see the task running on the EMR.

The Airflow I am using is running **LocalExecutor** and I wanted to know how to kill a running task.

**Should i be using the "Clear" option from the UI to stop the running task?** or use the clear task as well as some code changes

Below is my code

```
def execute_on_emr(cmd):
    f = open(file,'r')
    s = f.read()
    keyfile = StringIO.StringIO(s)
    mykey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key(keyfile)
    sshcon   = paramiko.SSHClient()
    sshcon.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    sshcon.connect(IP, username=username, pkey=mykey)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = sshcon.exec_command(cmd)
    logger.info("stdout ------>"+str(stdout.readlines()))
    logger.info("Error--------->"+str(stderr.readlines()))
    if (stdout.channel.recv_exit_status())!= 0:
        logger.info("Error Return code not Zero:"+ 
        str(stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()))
        sys.exit(1)
    

Task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='XXX',
    python_callable=execute_on_emr,
    op_kwargs={'cmd': 'spark-submit /hadoop/scripts.py'},
    dag=dag)
```

My question is how to i kill/stop the task from the Airflow UI so the task running on the EMR too gets killed.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,Chetan

Answer (score 0):

This is implemented as of [this PR](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2877) which is recently merged into master.

If you are able to run airflow from master I would suggest you try that. Otherwise, work is underway for releasing 1.10 which would include this feature.